# UITableview background color when using Search Bar

Tags: iphone

I used searchbar with my UITableview. When I enter search text, the background color will be changed automatically as white color.

and also I used:

```
tableView.bounces=FALSE;
```

When I used searchbar, that time bounces also, won't work.

The output like as follows:

[image]

1. I need to change background color, when I searching content.
2. I need:

   tableView.bounces=FALSE;

will work, when I searching content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer for my question:

```
  -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
 {
UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
[controller.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: patternImage]];
controller.searchResultsTableView.bounces=FALSE;
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color of the cell to clearcolor and while reloading the table at the time of search set its(tables) background color as black.

Comment: i used the following     tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  tableView.opaque = NO;
  tableView.backgroundView = nil;
                 but it wont work

Comment: thats what i am telling your cell s background color wont be clear. So first of set the background color of cell as clearcolor in cellforrowatindex

Comment: i used the following also  ..... it also doesnt work                                                                        [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];